# What to do about [tag:nfc] and [tag:near-field-communication]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently we have two tags for NFC:

- [nfc](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfc), 44 questions and no excerpt
- [near-field-communication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-field-communication), 27 questions and this excerpt:

  > NFC is a short-range wireless technology, typically requiring a distance of 4cm or less to initiate a connection between two endpoints.

A quick inspection shows that all the questions seem to be about the same thing. I would say that this is a clear case of tag duplication. What needs to be done about these two tags?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*To simplify voting I will post my suggested solution here as an answer instead of as part of the question.*

I think we should keep [nfc](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfc) as the main tag, and make the other a synonym. Three letter abbrivations are annoying, but in this case I think the term NFC is much more well established than near field communication.

We can move the tag excerpt from [near-field-communication](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-field-communication) to [nfc](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nfc).

Comment: Also, a synonym might be nice.

Comment: Boom, completed.

Comment: Just want to add that all other tags have synonyms the other way, like ai->artificial-intelligence, which I would argue is an equally well established abbreviation, if not even more.